# How to smooth a zoo series in R

Tags: r, smoothing, zoo

I would like to smooth a zoo time series (a zoo object) in R.
I've already performed the classic moving average smoothing, but I would like to try other methods, such as the kernel smoothing or others, but nothing seems to work, because the function returns a list and NOT a zoo time series! So, when I try to plot it, I can't.

```
data.smoothKER <- ksmooth(time(data), data, "normal", bandwidth = 3)
plot(data.smoothKER, datazoo)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

What can I do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and describe the kind of output you want

Comment: If the question is how to create a zoo series from `K <- ksmooth(...)`  then `z <- read.zoo(data.frame(K))`